# Why does my decimal conversion return null?

Tags: sql, hive

Why the decimal conversion turned to be null.

```sql
select  CAST(CAST(TRIM('0000000059900') as DECIMAL)/10000 AS DECIMAL(13,4));
```

`5.9900` -- this got converted correctly

But below one turned out to be `null` whereas expected is - `1467203.9400`

```sql
select  CAST(CAST(TRIM('0014672039400') as DECIMAL)/10000 AS DECIMAL(13,4));
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: select  CAST(CAST(TRIM('0014672039400') as DECIMAL(13,0))/10000 AS DECIMAL(13,4));
Achieved with this

Comment: I would convert to INT.

Answer (score 1):

DECIMAL Defaults to decimal(10,0) which does not fit your second query.

You can fix it by specifying precision like 20,5

Example:

```
select  CAST(CAST(TRIM('0014672039400') as DECIMAL(20,5))/10000 AS DECIMAL(13,4));

INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=hive_20230523181353_0134e304-4ae6-4e9a-aa6e-c6f6b7bfa56e): select  CAST(CAST(TRIM('0014672039400') as DECIMAL(20,5))/10000 AS DECIMAL(13,4))
INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
INFO  : Created Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:_c0, type:decimal(13,4), comment:null)], properties:null)
INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hive_20230523181353_0134e304-4ae6-4e9a-aa6e-c6f6b7bfa56e); Time taken: 0.208 seconds
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hive_20230523181353_0134e304-4ae6-4e9a-aa6e-c6f6b7bfa56e): select  CAST(CAST(TRIM('0014672039400') as DECIMAL(20,5))/10000 AS DECIMAL(13,4))
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20230523181353_0134e304-4ae6-4e9a-aa6e-c6f6b7bfa56e); Time taken: 0.001 seconds
+---------------+
|      _c0      |
+---------------+
| 1467203.9400  |
+---------------+
1 row selected (0.242 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-DecimalsdecimalDecimals